# How to Use WMS and WFS in Android

Tags: android, dictionary, wms

I am completly new in the whole Geo IT materia :/, and my task is to check some ways to view a map in Android, overlayed with Vector data.

I have an WMS and WFS service where I can get the Data. But how can I integrate this in Android ?

Google Maps Api is not Free for use comercial right ?
Nutiteq, too ?
Does osmdroid supports stuff like wms/wfs ?
what about mapforge ? Mapforge is only for offline maps right ?

Does someone got nice tutorials how to build such maps ?

Whats about Shape Files, can i combine a osm map tiles with shape files which contain the vector data ?

I know that are much questions, at the moment i feel like a fish thrown in a new sea.
I would be very happy if someone could help me a bit :)

and sorry 4 my bad english.

Regards Matthias

Comment: Nutiteq new library version (http://nutiteq.github.com/hellomap3d/) is free if you use OpenStreetMap as base map. It can do WMS out of box. There is WFS experimental support, but this is not ready/public yet.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can check this link :
[Using getTileURL in Android Application with GeoServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553715/using-gettileurl-in-android-application-with-geoserver?rq=1)

i'm also in progress to build my application that use WMS in android. i'm using Geoserver as server. so far, it's running well. i think [this link](http://www.azavea.com/blogs/labs/2013/01/wms-on-android/) is enough to give you tutorial how to use wms in android.
i hope it helps.
i'm sorry if my english is not good enough

Answer (score -1):

Implements WMS, WMS-C(ontext), and WFS

http://openscales.org/

OpenScales is an open source (LGPL) mapping framework written in ActionScript 3 and Flex that enables developers to build Rich Internet Mapping Applications.

Desktop and mobile (Android, iOS) applications can both be created using OpenScales. See our YouTube channel.

iPad-Viewer will be proposed at the beginning of 2012.

Cheers

Comment: not a reliable source. too much efforts in development and most important not in active development as there is no new version release since 2012