# Can I use Android Google Map API without Useing Maps from Google

Tags: android, google-maps

I would like to use own WMS/WFS Services, like Orthophotos. Is it possible to use the Google Android Map API to load this Maps ?

Because when using the Google Maps comercial, I have to buy a Google Premier licence right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use the Google Android Map API to load this Maps ?

No, you can't pass your own maps to Google Maps framework on Android.

You can use special tools for such purposes. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14283055/782599).

> Because when using the Google Maps comercial, I have to buy a Google Premier licence right ?

No. For Android you can use Google Maps API even if your app is payed. Read more [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-maps-api/dm4K72FMKME/IjW6OEnWXUsJ)

Comment: Ok I can use the Google Android Map API free, and I am not able to use my Map Data instead of Googles Data. Can I use the Map Services free on Android, too ? Too include my data is only possible by creating Overlays right ?

Comment: You can use the maps for free.  You just have to register to get an API.  You can put your data on it using the overlays.

Comment: @MatthiasH in Google Maps API v2 you can use only polygons, polylines and markers as overlays on map.

Comment: @MatthiasH So if you want to use different tiles then you need another library for displaying map. If you want to use OSM then you can use one of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14335741/782599) libraries. Decide what provider you need and search android library for it using Google :).
btw: If you like this answer - don't forget to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks for all this Information, I will try out using osmdroid, and using Tiles from osm. And will try drawing own Polygons over the rasterdata...I thought it would be cool and easy, using the Google Maps Android API and using overlays to draw my Vector an Rasterdata :(. Then there is no WMS/WFS Support in Google Maps API v2 ?

Comment: @MatthiasH no, Google Maps API v2 doesn't represent such feature.

Comment: @Steven Can you use Google maps on android with enterprise data?  I'm talking about the free api.  Haven't found a clear answer here...

Comment: @Patrick Are you talking about Maps Android API V2 or JavaScript API V3.  Are you displaying these with the native maps or through a webview?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to; I think Google API's can only be used for Google services. Why you have to look for an another service when Google provides the easiest map services and Google API's are free and no need to pay for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't. If you want to avoid google, try this:

1. [OSMdroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/)
2. [Mapsforge](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/)
3. [MapQuest](http://devblog.mapquest.com/2011/11/17/no-preset-limit-on-free-map-api-transactions/)

It's free